# Sub site mapping in IIS

Tags: linux, apache, azure, iis

I have a site `www.test.com` hosted in IIS(Azure VM). I have a WordPress site hosted in Apache(Linux VM) in another server.

I need to map `www.test.com/example` to the WordPress site.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options that come to mind:

- Have IIS on Windows IIS box in Azure redirect that path to your other Wordpress site.  This won't change the DNS name of the Wordpress box but will simple just redirect.
- Use a web application gateway in Azure([article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-url-route-arm-ps)) or some other web routing appliance (VM) to act as your termination point for the www.test.com traffic.  Then have it redirect that URL path to your Linux VM.   In the containers world this is done with an Ingress controller.